# php, ajax error reporting is not working

Tags: php, ajax, error-reporting

i have this file and on a click event it calls a php function through `$.post{}`
i have used `alert(data)` to recognized errors. But unfortunately its not allerting anything except it shows an error on firebug console with relevant url `"Internal server error 500"` and then i tried to access the code through browser pasting the full url, I have put `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` , but shows a blank page. I'm lost here no idea how to solve this without any errors displaying.. Help much appreciated.

p.s in php info error reporting is off. i tried htaccess on my subfolder without no luck either.

Comment: its actually jquery `$.post(url_file, { all: all, prebody:body ,currant_url :location.href, pre_content:globle_pre_content, post_content:globle_post_content},
       function(data){
       alert( data);
       });`

Comment: thanks anyway i got it working . the client has replace index file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following:

- `error_reporting(E_ALL)` is right after `<?php` tag
- There is indeed a PHP error - try to deliberately make one. Maybe the error is elsewhere, not your PHP but the .htaccess file (since you're getting 500), or maybe it's a logical error.

Comment: thanks anyway i got it working . the client has replace index file.